# Create universal method for entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some code which duplicate in many methods:

```
IQueryable<СollectorTable> сollectors = ctx.СollectorTable.Where(x => x.Date >= (DateTime)d.StartDate && x.Date <= (DateTime)d.EndDate);

if (d.NId.Count != 0)
    сollectors = сollectors.Where(x => d.NId.Contains(x.NId));
if (d.PId.Count != 0)
    сollectors = сollectors.Where(x => d.PId.Contains(x.PId ?? -1));
if (d.BId.Count != 0)
    сollectors = сollectors.Where(x => d.BId.Contains(x.BId ?? -1));

.....
some code with сollectors  work
```

I would like create some universal method, but I don't know as.
I trying use `<T>` but it didn't give me results.

Comment: Can you elaborate, why do you have this code multiple times, and what is the difference between all the different versions

Comment: It is my web-api project for selected data form Db. And if i set (NId, PId, BId) need selected data for this three filters or if some parameters not set need select just some data.

Comment: I duplicated this code because I use him in different methods

Comment: why not have all the calls go to the same controller, calling the same method

Comment: because it is filters for diferent tables but with same properties

Comment: Is it returning the same dataset

Comment: What is the body variable?

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil ooops I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a guess at some of your types above - if you are able to add an interface to anything with NId, PId, BId properties then you could create the interface:

```
public interface ICollectorTable
{
    int? NId { get; }
    int? PId { get; }
    int? BId { get; }
}
```

and an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterCollectors<T>(this IQueryable<T> collectors, SomeObject d)
        where T : ICollectorTable
    {
        if (d.NId.Count() != 0)
            collectors = collectors.Where(x => d.NId.Contains(x.NId));
        if (d.PId.Count() != 0)
            collectors = collectors.Where(x => d.PId.Contains(x.PId ?? -1));
        if (d.BId.Count() != 0)
            collectors = collectors.Where(x => d.BId.Contains(x.BId ?? -1));

        return collectors;
    }
}
```

Then the code in your question would become:

```
IQueryable<СollectorTable> сollectors = ctx.СollectorTable.Where(x => x.Date >= (DateTime)d.StartDate && x.Date <= (DateTime)d.EndDate);

collectors = collectors.FilterCollectors(d);
.....
some code with сollectors  work
```